# Why KENDO Grid in Inline Editing mode Doesn't pass the new User?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid

I have below "Kendo" grid in inline editing Mode , it will do the CRUD But and I just wrote the Edit yet.
But when I put a break-point On my `[HttpPost]` function all properties of `ExternalUser` class is Null.

```
  @(Html.Kendo().Grid<DBLayer.ViewModels.User.ExternalUser>()
    .Name("grid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(c => c.Username);
        columns.Bound(c => c.Name);
        columns.Bound(c => c.Surname);
        columns.Command(command => command.Edit()).Width(150);
        columns.Command(command => command.Destroy()).Width(150);
    })
      .ToolBar(toolBar =>
      {
          toolBar.Template(@<text><a class="btn btn-primary" href="@Url.Action("Insert","User")" >create</a></text>);
      })
.Pageable()
.Sortable()
.Scrollable()
.HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:550px;" })
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
    .Ajax()
    .Batch(true)
    .ServerOperation(false)
    .Events(events => events.Error("error_handler"))
    .Model(model =>
    {
        model.Id(p => p.ProfileId);
    })
    .PageSize(20)
    .Read(read => read.Action("Users_Read", "User"))
    .Update(update => update.Action("Update", "User"))
    .Destroy(destroy => destroy.Action("EditingCustom_Destroy", "User"))
)
```

)

And here is my Action :

```
    public ActionResult Insert()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Insert([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request,ExternalUser user)
    {
    }
```

Sorry about the large amount of code dumped, its just all related and I believe the error lies somewhere.

Comment: Try changing parameter like this: `public ActionResult Insert([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, int ProfileId)`, is just passing `ProfileId` work properly? If int parameter works, then model class defined in grid should made a mess as action parameter. Also I want to see properties inside `ExternalUser`.

Comment: I changed Update function : `public ActionResult Update([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, Guid ProfileId)
        {
            var user = Facade.UserBO.GetUserById(ProfileId);
            return Json(new[] { user }.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState));
        }` , now I have error : `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)`

Comment: HTTP 500 indicates unhandled exception inside `Update` action. In which line the exception thrown? Also you're still not showing `ExternalUser` viewmodel properties, which may causing the problem.

Comment: ` public class ExternalUser
    {
        public Guid ProfileId { set; get; }
        public string Name { set; get; }
        public string Surname { set; get; }
        public string Username { set; get; }
        public string OrganizationId { set; get; }
        public string PersonnelNumber { set; get; }
        public string StatusId { set; get; }
        public int ProfileHead { set; get; }
        public string username { set; get; }
        public string fname { set; get; }
        public string lname { set; get; }
    }`

Comment: The exception is on view when I clicked on Update button and it doesn't work , I pressed F12 and copy the error

Comment: I see that your model is not the one causing null value in `ExternalUser`, how about using `public ActionResult Insert([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, ExternalUser externalUser)` instead? Probably model binder already recognizes `user` as something else and changing parameter name may suffice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this binding to the DataSource:

```
.Create(create => create.Action("Insert", "User"))
```

Also you must add the k-grid-save-changes class to your toolbar button. Change the toolbar button for the following:

```
toolBar.Template(@<text><a class="btn btn-primary k-grid-save-changes" href="javascript:;">create</a></text>);
```

Result:

```
 @(Html.Kendo().Grid<DBLayer.ViewModels.User.ExternalUser>()
.Name("grid")
.Columns(columns =>
{
    columns.Bound(c => c.Username);
    columns.Bound(c => c.Name);
    columns.Bound(c => c.Surname);
    columns.Command(command => command.Edit()).Width(150);
    columns.Command(command => command.Destroy()).Width(150);
})
  .ToolBar(toolBar =>
  {
      toolBar.Template(@<text><a class="btn btn-primary k-grid-save-changes" href="javascript:;">create</a></text>);
  })
.Pageable()
.Sortable()
.Scrollable()
.HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:550px;" })
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
.Ajax()
.Batch(true)
.ServerOperation(false)
.Events(events => events.Error("error_handler"))
.Model(model =>
{
    model.Id(p => p.ProfileId);
})
.PageSize(20)
.Read(read => read.Action("Users_Read", "User"))
.Create(create => create.Action("Insert", "User"))
.Update(update => update.Action("Update", "User"))
.Destroy(destroy => destroy.Action("EditingCustom_Destroy", "User"))
)
```